# cannot install Open NFC

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I downloaded the `Open NFC SDK for Android v4.4.1 (13751).zip` file from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.4.1%20%2813312%29/Open%20NFC%20SDK%20for%20Android%20v4.4.1%20%2813751%29.zip/download) and copied the `addon_open_nfc_4.4.1_android_4.0.3` folder into `sdk\add-ons`. If I open the android SDK Manager from the IDE, the Open NFC entry does not sho up, while if I open it trough the `SDK Manager.exe` in my Andriod SDK install directory it shows up in the list but has a red broken icon next to it.
[image]
So it says unable to find base platform with API level 15, but it seems I have SDK platform for API 17 installed. Moreover, the Open NFC emulator does not appear in the target drop down menu when I try to create new device in Android Virtual Device Manager. What do I need to do to be able to test some basic NFC programs? Is there any step by step tutorial that shows how to do this?

SDK version:

> Android Developer Tools
>
> Build: v22.0.1-685705

Comment: And if you download and install API 15, does the NFC SDK install correctly?

Comment: If I install API 15 will it disturb my current configuration in any way?

Comment: Adding APIs to the SDK shouldn't hurt anything. If you need more of a walkthru for NFC, look at: http://www.tappednfc.com/android-nfc-developer-guide/

Comment: Hi @user13267 , I am also having the same problem? did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Any solutions yet? even my sdk manager doesn't show up the open nfc